# Get the largest rectangle in a quadrilateral

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems

So I have coordinates for a few shapes with 4 sides of varying angles. I need to find the largest rectangle in them, even if the rectangle is rotated. Is there an algorithm for this?

In the example image below I have the coords for the orange quadrilaterals and I'm looking for the grey rectangle inside, more specifically the coordinate for each green dot.

Any ideas or could someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548660/finding-the-largest-rectangle-inside-a-quadrilateral

Comment: @ShravanYadav Neither of those examples above deals with rotating the rectangle inside the shape to take a large area

Comment: why to rotate the rectangle if you can get the largest rectangle in the 1st calculation.